# Probability problem - binomial theorem and conditional distribution

Tags: probability

I've just solved this problem. I'd like to know if my reasoning was correct(basically my doubt is about Q3):

Mark and Sarah have the following collection of vinyl records

|  | Jazz | Funk | Rock | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mark | 3 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| Sarah | 5 | 1 | 1 | 4 |

Q1: Mark and Sarah randomly choose a vinyl record. What's the probability of choosing an either jazz or Sarah's vinyl records?

My answer: let J be the event of choosing a jazz record, $P(J)=8/19$; and let S be the probability of choosing a Sarah's vinyl record, $P(S)=11/19$, and $P(J \cap S)=5/19$

$P(J \cup S)=14/19$, Right?

Q2: Mark and Sarah decide to listen 5 vinyl records, once per time. Once a vinyl record has listened, then is put back. Let $X$ be the number of times a Jazz or Sarah's vinyl record has been listened. Compute $P(X \ge 2)$

My answer: by using the PMF of the Binomial distribution, I computed: $P(X \ge 2)=1-P(X=0)-P(X=1)=0.98$, Right?

Q3: Sarah lends 3 randomly chosen vinyl records to Frank, her new friend. What's the probability that 2 vinyl records are Jazz?

My answer: my computation has been: $\frac{5}{11} \frac{4}{10} \frac{6}{9}$. Is that correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first two answers are correct.

Since Sarah has eleven vinyl records, there are $\binom{11}{3}$ ways for her to randomly select three of her records.  To choose exactly two jazz records from her collection, she must choose two of the five jazz records and one of the six other records.  Hence, the probability that Sarah lends Frank *exactly two* jazz records is
$$\frac{\dbinom{5}{2}\dbinom{6}{1}}{\dbinom{11}{3}}$$
The probability that Sarah lends Frank *at least two* jazz records is
$$\frac{\dbinom{5}{2}\dbinom{6}{1} + \dbinom{5}{3}}{\dbinom{11}{3}}$$

*Why is your answer incorrect?*

You used an ordered selection without taking into account the different orders in which Sarah could have given Frank two jazz records and one record from a different genre.

On the assumption that exactly two jazz records were meant, you only considered the possibility that Sarah first gives Frank two jazz records and then a record from another genre.  However, there are three orders in which she could have given two jazz records and one record from a different genre.  Therefore, you need to multiply your answer by three.

$$\frac{5}{11} \cdot \frac{4}{10} \cdot \frac{6}{9} + \frac{5}{11} \cdot \frac{6}{10} \cdot \frac{4}{9} + \frac{6}{11} \cdot \frac{5}{10} \cdot \frac{4}{9} = 3 \cdot \frac{5}{11} \cdot \frac{4}{10} \cdot \frac{6}{9} = \frac{\dbinom{5}{2}\dbinom{6}{1}}{\dbinom{11}{3}}$$